# Finding property usage counts with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dependencies, code-analysis

I have a generated file with around 10,000 public static properties and methods. I suspect that a nontrivial number of them are entirely unused, but there are around 50 assemblies and millions of lines of code to check to be sure.

What I would like to do is run some kind of utility that can look into all of the compiled assemblies we have and tell me exactly which members of this class are being called, and give me counts for each one.

Is such a thing possible with reflection, or do I need to revert to actual code analysis tools? Are there any libraries that can analyze assemblies to find their dependencies within another assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReSharper "Find Usages Advanced" feature has an option to find references in Libraries as well as in the current Solution.  I haven't used this particular feature, so I'm not sure how well it works (the Find Usages within a solution works quite nicely), but you can get a trial version of ReSharper and try it.  My guess is that you'll need to run it from a Solution that has a Project with references to the various Libraries you're interested in.

Comment: This is currently what I am doing. Problems are: I have to load ALL code into a single solution. VS chokes pretty hard. I also have to check every property individually. I would like to integrate this into the build process to detect unused properties.

Comment: @CMP, I believe the Find Usages Advanced will allow you to do this without having to load the code into the solution (just need a stub project with the assembly references.)  This does still require checking each property in turn, which is definitely not ideal.  It sounds like what you may need is a code analysis tool like FxCop; you might be able to configure it to only report 'unused symbol' warnings.

Comment: That's a good idea. One of my other aims is to potentially partition the properties based on what is used where, so I would like to visualize a graph of calls to see if patterns emerge. That may solve my unused properties problem though.

Comment: @CMP, ReSharper has a View Call Hierarchy tool (Ctrl+K Ctrl+T) that you can use on a particular member, but that requires the actual Project sources to be loaded into a Solution.  It also doesn't really do partitioning, since it's only one property at a time.  On a side note, I've noticed that VS performance with large solutions (100+ projects) increased dramatically when I installed a solid state drive; might be worth considering if this is slowing you down.

Comment: Looks like adding a bunch of the most likely solutions and using resharper is my best bet. NDepend can give pretty good metrics as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with "regular" reflection, since *usages* cannot be detected by looking only at the *structure* of the classes. I guess you'll need to disassemble the IL and analyze it, looking for `call`, `calli`, and `callvirt` instructions (property lookups are also method calls). You can get the IL for a method with `typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("Method").GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()`, but it might be hard to analyze it when it's in the form of a byte array. You might want to look into [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil), which might help you analyze the bytecode.

Of course, there might well exist tools for this already.