# Reflection & WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, parsing, reflection

I want to get a list of all the Operations\Methods from a webservice that are consumed by an application. For example: if a there is a webservice1 and application A is consuming Webservice1 then i want to be able to somehow find out all the operations that application A is consuming.I'm not interested in list of all the methods that are being exposed by the web service Interface but only interested in the one being consumed in the application.

I'm trying to use Reflection to Load the Application Assembly.Using Reflection i was able to narrow down the Service  references in the application and also am able to get the list of operations exposed the web service interface but not able to get any handle how to get the list of operations consumed in the application? Can we get such information through Reflection?

Comment: not to the extent you describe - the "consuming" can help in several ways, even with reflection...

Comment: I'm not 100% but I think you would have to scan the il code of every method to do that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599075/finding-property-usage-counts-with-reflection might be helpful

Comment: It isn't exactly what you're asking for, but you may be able to use a network sniffer (like Wireshark) to figure out exactly which operations are being used. It isn't a perfect solution though (it won't work for named pipe transport for example), but it would definitely be easier than trying to use reflection to do it.

Comment: @Bahri - Thanks for the article.I'm able to get to the byte array using the MethodBody but i'm still not sure if I'm headed the right way.Is this Byte array for the Operations being Used?

Comment: @Babcock-I'll look into the Sniffer option but right now i want to confirm if i achieve this through reflection.

Comment: @NuttyAngel The byte array is the byte code for the method (from the IL). With some engineering, you should be able to determine the methods that are being called, and match them with the methods on your Web Service proxy.

Comment: Please don't add "C#" to the ends of your titles. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to statically predict what operations a client might call on a WCF service. One convenient way to discover what the client does actually call is to have the server generate a WCF trace.

Comment: The method calls to the proxy class can be determined, or Find Usages would not be possible.  I'm assuming Nutty is trying to replicate that behavior, since he's obviously smart enough to use the built in tools or buy ReSharper if he just wanted the calls for a specific proxy.